# iCloud storage iPhone backup

Tags: iphone, icloud

2 iPhones show on my iPad as being backed up. I only have one, so I guess one is my old phone. I would like to delete it but I'm not sure which one I should delete, I don't want to remove the wrong one.
How can I tell which is which?

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://www.icloud.com/#settings which should show all registered devices & their names. Using the device name, model & even Serial Number or IMEI info, you can decide which to delete.